# Implementing Domain login on 200 computers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, openldap

WE have about 200 computers that are to be put under domain login on linux  with a ubuntu server .(ie The users will login to the client systems using authentication information stored on a central server over the network)

I heard about LDAP and openLdap to implement this but I am not sure as to what the procedure is .
I did try some references , but still I am quite un-certain as to wheather this can be done .

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one documentation to follow, [try this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/FreeIPA_Guide/index.html).

Your needs will be met by Freeipa, which is a super-charged implementation of Ldap.
If you are not good with Linux, ldap and related things, you may need to get dedicated support.